# Progress bar shows incorrect speed when copying files to nfs mounted storage

Tags: nfs, zfs, file-transfer, file-manager

I have a strange problem with a nfs mounted drive. It's a zfs pool shared via nfs, both server and client use Linux Mint 18.1.

What happens is that when I copy a larger file to the server, the progress bar hits 100 % almost immediately (with some ridiculous speed) and then just hangs before the actual transfer completes. So far I tried two file managers (MATE's default Caja and Double Commander) with the same result.

Interestingly, when I copy in the opposite direction (from server to client) it all works as expected.

I suspect this could be the property of the NFS protocol itself - how it reports on the amount of transferred data or something. I'm not sure.

**I have two questions:**

1. Is this normal or is it a bug, possibly?
2. If not a bug, is there a way to configure it to play nicely with progress bars?

My */etc/exports* looks like this:

```
    /media/data        192.168.2.1/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

I also tried *async*, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: You are dealing with buffering in RAM ; the client just copies everything to a buffer, and I bet it waits  until it is notified by the server of the success of the operation. I clearly know the buffer detail, though I do not remember the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with either of those file managers.  Have you tried a simple copy?  ie:  `timex cp <X> <Y>`

Perhaps the file managers are doing a check after the copy?  Possibly some kind of checksum/md5 hash check?

Version on NFS in use?  zpool on server ok?  `zpool status -x`

Comment: And I'm not familiar with `timex`. Did you mean `time`? Anyway, `cp` combined with time would only tell me how long it takes to copy the file. I'm interested in seeing the correct percentage of transmitted data while copying.

I'm sure it's a simple copy without any checks.

It's NFS v4 and the zpool is healthy.

Comment: Oops, Solaris hat for timex cmd.  But basically, I was wondering if using the `cp` command gave you better results, as well as gathering additional data in determining the discrepancies/oddities that you're seeing.  Which may also help hint if it's a FS or file manager issue.